# find all divs which contains anchor to it's next with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find all the *div* which must are having one and onlyone anchor next to it with JQuery
i.e

```
<div>
</div>
<a></a>

<div>
</div>


<div>
</div>
<a></a>
```

For example above acc to my requirement I want to the first and third as the output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these cases, go backwards *from* the anchor, like this:

```
$("a").prev("div")
```

This gets the `<a>` elements, then gets the `<div>` immediately before *if* it's a `<div>` using [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Clearly the best way to do it. +1

Comment: But this also styles divs with two anchors next to them i.e. `<div></div><a></a><a></a>` which was not requested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).next("a").length;
}).hide();
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SjWAq/)

Comment: Your CSS doesn't work. It will select all sibling divs following an `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This gives all anchors following a div

```
var els = $("div + a")
```

so building on Nick's answer this should work

```
var els = $("div + a").prev();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
and specifically `Next Adjacent Selector`

Making sure that there is only one anchor after the div means doing a little more filtering

You can find all divs with more than one anchor directly following using

```
$("div + a + a").prev().prev();
```

so could use that if you need to exclude that case.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ySuZm/2/

Comment: Note that this selects the *anchors* rather than the `<div>` elements though :)

Comment: The first line selects the anchors, the second selects the div before it.